# SQL Server 2012 Calculate total with tax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, math, calculator

there needs to be 3 columns

the tax needs to be 13%

the tax amount needs to be added to the InvoiceTotal the amount that it adds needs to be put in the tax column and the InvoiceTotal needs to be added by the Tax amount and put into the Total Column but only if the InvoiceTotal is greater then 0$ aka if there is a balance owed

InvoiceTotal is the only place you need to draw data from and InvoiceTotal is a column in the tables called Invoices

Structure below:

InvoiceTotal  Tax  Total

Comment: I got all the invoicetotals into a column but i can't get it to calculate the tax and input that into the tax column

Comment: You can improve your question a lot. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more information on that. You will receive better answers (and maybe even reputation points) by asking better questions. Good luck!

Comment: @CalebSmith You are new at SQL, and won't learn if provided a full packaged answer. Show us the point you are atuck at. What is your query so far?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want this:

```
select invoicetotal,
    invoicetotal * .13 as tax,
    invoicetotal * 1.13 as total
from invoices
where invoicetotal > 0
```